# VHDL syntax error using with-select statement

Tags: syntax-error, vhdl

I am writing a code for a seven segment decoder for a project yet when I check for syntax errors it shown me those:

> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at sevenseg.vhd(16) near text "with"; expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("with" is a reserved keyword), or a sequential statement
>
> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at sevenseg.vhd(17) near text "when"; expecting ";"

My code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity sevenseg is
    port (m3, m2, m1, m0:in std_logic;
            out7 : out std_logic_vector (6 downto 0));
end sevenseg;

architecture ssdec of sevenseg is
    signal min : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
begin
    process(m0, m1, m2, m3)
begin
    min <= m3 & m2 & m1 & m0; --concatenate m0, m1, m2, m3 into vector min
    
    with min select                                 --here is where the error specify
    out7    <=  "0111111"   when "0000" | "1010",   -- 0 
                "0000110"   when "0001" | "1011",   -- 1
                "1010111"   when "0010" | "1100",   -- 2
                "1001111"   when "0011" | "1101",   -- 3
                "1100110"   when "0100" | "1110",   -- 4
                "1101101"   when "0101" | "1111",   -- 5
                "1111100"   when "0110",            -- 6
                "0000111"   when "0111",            -- 7
                "1111111"   when "1000",            -- 8
                "1100111"   when "1001";            -- 9

end process;
end ssdec;
```

What are the errors and how I correct it, thanks.

Comment: It's called a selected signal assignment. See IEEE Std 1076-2008 10. Sequential statements, 10.5 Signal assignment statements, 10.5.4 Selected signal assignments. Before revision -2008 Selected signal assignment was only available as a concurrent statement (e.g. -2002 9 Concurrent statements, 9.5 Concurrent signal assignment statements, 9.5.2 Selected signal assignments). Also see -2008 11.6 Concurrent signal assignment statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VHDL versions prior to 2008, `with..select` statements can only be used outside of a process. So to fix the error, either:

1. move the with..select outside of the process
2. Use VHDL 2008 or later

If you go with 2. above you will also need to add `min` to the process sensitivity list.

You also have an issue that there is no "others" choice in the with..select. ALL cases must be covered in a `with..select`. Because `min` is a std_logic_vector, you must cover all combinations of all of the 9 idividual state types. Hence `when others` is usually the best way to cover everything.